# IntelliJ IDEA 2022, how to set order of services in multiple Spring Boot microservices system?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2022, how to set order of services in multiple Spring Boot microservices system?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Drag then drop order in what you want.

[image]

Comment: That is a great tip. In my environment, however, I need a certain service to complete initialization before others can start. This solution only defines start order but no "wait for start complete".

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order in which they are launch in Edit Configuration -> Modify options -> Add before launch task. You add a new configuration that launches all your services in the order you want

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the solution I was looking for.  Note: A service specified in `Add before launch task` should not be added to the `Spring Boot` list (in the left pane), otherwise it will be run twice.